# declare textbox key press event code at some other place and call it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

i need to handle keypress event of my textboxes so that the user enters only numeric data in the textboxes, i have my code which is working fine and im posting it below, but my concern is that, i have more than 30 textboxes with the same requirement and i dont want to write the same code for the key press events of the 30 textboxes, but i cannot write this code in a method and call that method..is there any way i can solve this issue so that i can wrilte the code at one place and call it in al the key press events of the textboxes or any other way which makes my code look standard and reduce the lines, im posting my code below

```
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if (e.KeyChar == '.'
            && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use one event handler for all text boxes

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.KeyPress += tb_KeyPress;

TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
tb2.KeyPress += tb_KeyPress;

  void tb_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
    && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
    && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if (e.KeyChar == '.'
        && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry, but where should i write this code TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.KeyPress += tb_KeyPress;....?

Comment: @where do you create your text boxes?

Comment: direct drag and drop..winforms

Comment: @adityaa write the function void tb_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){... somewhere in the class. then select your all textboxes on the form, switch from properties to events and choose tb_KeyPress as event handler for KeyPress event

Comment: okk, im wrting this code in keypress events of all my textboxes and its wroking...textBox4.KeyPress += tb_KeyPress; where textbox4 is the id of my textbox, is this the right way?

Comment: @adityaa not wrong, but not nice. if you created all textboxes in designer, then select tb_KeyPress as event handler in designer as well as I described above